# Packaging a maven project into a zip file via maven

Tags: java, maven, packaging

With maven, is it possible to create a zip file of my maven project?  The zip file should also contain the pom.xml file and all others.  The zip file is the archive of the maven project.  Basically, I just want my user to easily import the project into Eclipse after unpacking the zip file.

How do I achieve this with maven?

Thanks!

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837778/maven-best-practice-for-creating-ad-hoc-zip-artifact

Comment: and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078028/how-to-create-zip-target-instead-of-jar-in-maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use antrun plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <zip destfile="d:/projectname.zip" basedir="${project.basedir}" excludes="target/**" />
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

run it from Eclipse `Run As -> Maven build... -> Goals: antrun:run`

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this using maven-assembly-plugin that Pradeep suggested.

And also using maven-antrun-plugin.
See the [pom](http://buildbox.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/buildbox/trunk/testdata/svn-mvn-testdata/pom.xml?revision=2549&view=markup&pathrev=4000) and zip task. Include the files that you want in fileset.