# How to create zip target instead of jar in maven?

Tags: java, maven, jar, zip, maven-assembly-plugin

Can someone please help me in creating a zip target instead of jar in maven. I tried several ways but couldn't progress. Given descriptor file in the assembly path is as follows:

```
<assembly>
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>src/main</directory>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
</assembly>
```

The assembly plugin section in my pom file is as follows:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/descriptor.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Final Output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ sql1 ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Divakar\mvn_project\sql1\target\sql1-0.1.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

Comment: nice, and just to keep it simple, you should make the pom's packaging `pom` so that no jar is produced as standard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to bind the plugin to a particular [build lifecycle phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#A_Build_Lifecycle_is_Made_Up_of_Phases) via execution like this:

```xml
<executions> 
  <execution>
    <id>make-zip</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>single</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
</executions>
```

Afterwards you can do it via `mvn clean package`.