# How to do custom packaging in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, zip, packaging

I want to create a `.zip` file instead of a `.jar` file when I run `mvn clean package`. The `.zip` file should have a directory structure as follows -

```
/
 |- bin
 |- conf
 |   |- All Property Files
 |- lib
     |- All JAR Files (packaged jar and its dependency jar OR a single fat jar)
```

I searched a lot but the only thing I end up getting is changing the directory structure of the main project folder and not the packaged content. I'm aware of various packaging types like JAR, WAR, EAR etc. but not sure if a `.zip` file can be made.

Is it possible to make a `.zip` instead of a JAR file? If so, how and can its directory structure be manipulated?

---

**Update:** Found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25078960/6042824) on how to create `.zip` files instead. But it doesn't contain info on changing directory structure.

---

**Update:** Solved it myself. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25078960/6042824) on how to create `.zip` files. It seems that tweaking with the `descriptor.xml` file will give me the desired result. Following is my `descriptor.xml` file.

```
<assembly>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
          <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
          <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
          <includes>
            <include>*.jar</include>
          </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
          <directory>${project.build.directory}/lib</directory>
          <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
          <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/config</directory>
          <outputDirectory>config</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
          <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/bin</directory>
          <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 3):

The dedicated Maven plugin for custom packaging is the [Maven Assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). 
It's possible using this plugin to change the packaging structure and type to:

- zip
- tar
- tar.gz (or tgz)
- tar.bz2 (or tbz2)
- jar
- dir
- war
- custom ( see ArchiveManager)

[There is the documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/generate-assembly.html) containing a sample of the plugin configuration.

According to the documentation, You'll need to:

- Set the format ( zip, tgz, ... )
- Activate the plugin for your current profile
- Define a specific package structure in the dedicated assembly bin.xml file found by default in the src/assembly folder
- And obviously, call the mvn package phase ( automatic during install ... ) so that the magic happens :)

Comment: Is it a good practice to keep the descriptor file in src/assembly or I can keep it anywhere because I'm keeping it in the project folder.

Comment: The **src/assembly** folder is not a source folder by default, so it will not be part of the final packaged project ( not delivered ).
     
The location and name of the file must be specified during the plugin configuration inside your POM. 

 `<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <descriptor>src/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>
        <finalName>my_super_project -${pom.version}</finalName>
       </configuration> ... `