# What's the recommended packaging for a "documentation" only module with Maven?

Tags: maven

I do not want to have the documentation of a multi-module Maven project under `site` folder for Maven Site workflow. The documentation lives under `project-docs` with the `project-parent`. What's the best practice `packaging` for such module?

The setup is

1. Packaging is now configured as `jar`
2. There's a Maven plugin that generates HTML/PDF documentation in phase `prepare-package` under some directory (`src/main/docs`) of `project-docs` during build workflow.
3. There's a `default` Maven assembly descriptor that generates a `project-docs-NNN-default.zip`.
4. The default artifact of the project is an **empty** JAR file.

Regarding the (3) in above, the alternatives:

#### Packaging: `pom`

Does not support `prepare-package` as the probably most suitable phase. If then phase `site` is used, you cannot have the generated documentation inside the default `install` life cycle.

#### Packaging: `jar`

The **empty** JAR is useless!

Comment: I would use JAR in your case, disabling the JAR plugin execution if you really do not want the empty JAR

Comment: The install life cycle is for jar or default life cycle whereas the site-deploy is for site life cycle so you could use `pre-site` for this.

Answer (score 3):

Since you do not want to use `site` generation for documentation, I **think there is no other "maven official way"** to perform it.

### Packaging

From my point of view, **you may use a standard POM packaging**, zip it through maven-assembly-plugin and add a classfier (doc or everything else).

#### related questions

Here some information to accomplish it :

- [Maven best practice for creating ad hoc zip artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837778/maven-best-practice-for-creating-ad-hoc-zip-artifact).
- [Maven - Depend on assembled zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298178/maven-depend-on-assembled-zip)

Even if it's already OK, there is interesting point there.

#### pom.xml

```xml
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>your-project</artifactId>
<version>1.1.0</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>doc-packaging</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>/src/main/assembly/doc.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Assembly descriptor : It will produce this artifact : your-project-**doc**.zip :

- this is (obviously) a zip archive
- the "classifier" is doc (like assembly name)

### Phase binding

Since pom doesn't have anything to prepare, you're right, there is no `prepare-package` phase ([as per doc](http://maven-guide-fr.erwan-alliaume.com/maven-guide-fr/site/reference/lifecycle-sect-pom.html)) . Indeed, your project aims to package doc ... so it would be correct to (re)bind your pdf plugin execution to `package`.