# How to create zip file with maven: Java Client + JRE

Tags: java, maven, zip, client

I want to package a java client together with a runtime into one Zip-file.

How should I do this with maven?

Java Client:

```
package com.test.client;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

This runs like:

```
java -cp "client.jar" com.test.Client
```

I want to deliver one zip-file with the jre: client.zip

```
/client.jar
/jre/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Apache Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

For datailed instructions, see [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/generate-assembly.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837778/maven-best-practice-for-creating-ad-hoc-zip-artifact).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the shade plugin https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/. This supersedes the assembly plugin I believe.

Comment: They serve quite different purposes. Neither supersedes either.