# Unable to create a JAR of my JDA project because of pom dependency

Tags: gradle, build, kotlin, dependencies, build.gradle

I have a Kotlin project with JDA API which I need to deploy on Heroku environment. To achieve that I created a JAR task in my `build.gradle` file.

```
jar {
    baseName = 'discord-stats-bot'
    version =  'v1'
    manifest {
        attributes('Main-Class': 'com.vchernogorov.discordbot.BotKt')
    }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

But I was unable to build this JAR file because of the following error.

```
16:02:03 vchernogorov $ ./gradlew jar
:kaptGenerateStubsKotlin UP-TO-DATE
:kaptKotlin UP-TO-DATE
:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:copyMainKotlinClasses UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
:jar

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not expand ZIP '/Users/vchernogorov/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/club.minnced/opus-java/1.0.4/596995aaf2f5b5091c4d251fdc11fa62680cc59e/opus-java-1.0.4.pom'.
> archive is not a ZIP archive

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.784 secs
```

This library is a dependency in a JDA project. So I need help with configuring this `jar` task in order to correctly build my executable and deploy it to Heroku.

Edit: Here's my `dependencies` block in `build.gradle`.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:0.16"
    compile "org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile "net.dv8tion:JDA:3.8.0_436"
    compile "khttp:khttp:0.1.0"
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the `dependencies` block?

Comment: Added `dependencies` block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In maven there's a [special](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692161/what-is-pom-packaging-in-maven) artifact of type `pom`. It is also published and downloaded as a dependency. In jar's `from` is neither a directory nor a jar file, that's why processing fails. To solve it you need to exclude the `*.pom` before collecting, so:

```
from {
   configurations
      .compile
      .findAll { !it.name.endsWith('pom') }
      .collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}
```

Next time you can use gradle shadow plugin or similar - a plugin that builds uber jar, since it probably handles it correctly.