# Why the JavaMoney dependency is packages as POM?

Tags: java, maven, java-money, jsr354

I am not very much experienced with build systems, but this got me curious.

Most libraries use `<type>jar</type>` (the default) for their dependencies, but the JavaMoney library uses `pom` instead, what's the reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is "pom" packaging in maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692161/what-is-pom-packaging-in-maven)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate because I want to understand why this decision was made. The link explains that there are Submodules in Maven and that's why it packages as POM.... But I have seen many projects with Submodules that output jars

Comment: Presumably, they decided that they didn't want the library to be packaged as a single JAR file.  Why?  Ask them!   (You have not given us a link to the POM file to look at **in context** ... so we don't actually know which of the many POMs you might be talking about.)

Comment: That's why I posted here, so they can answer, since they monitor the tags I included and this is the place for answering questions... I won't open an issue at their github repo since this isn't an issue... And a question in gitter gets lost

Comment: Well [good luck with that](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-money/topusers) :-)   Many developers have neither the time or the inclination to answer "why did you make that design decision" questions like this.

Comment: :/ I guess I am too spoiled by the Flutter team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause JavaMoney is multi module project and root of this projects has packaging pom.

When you declare dependency in pom.xml it will be attached to project with their transitive dependencies. This also work for artifacts with packaging pom. In this case transitive dependencies will be implementation of JavaMoney.

```
mvn dependency:tree
...
[INFO] +- org.javamoney:moneta:pom:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javamoney.moneta:moneta-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javamoney.moneta:moneta-convert:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javamoney.moneta:moneta-convert-imf:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javamoney.moneta:moneta-convert-ecb:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.money:money-api:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
```